# Avoid repeated views when checking optionals in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-optionals

I currently have this code:

```
if let isSaved = vm.place?.isSaved {
    Text(isSaved ? "Saved" : "Want to go")
} else {
    Text("Want to go")
}
```

How can I rewrite this to avoid having to essentially use the "Want to go" version of the `Text` view twice?

If I try just:

```
Text(vm.place?.isSaved ? "Saved" : "Want to go")
```

I get the error:

> Value of optional type 'Bool?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Bool'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `vm.place?.isSaved` returns `Optional<Bool>` which has `3` cases:

```
.none
.some(true)
.some(false)
```

Thats the reason you cant use the ternary operator directly.

You can get rid of the optionality by ignoring a case like:

```
Text(vm.place?.isSaved == true ? "Saved" : "Want to go")
```

or by giving it a default value like:

```
Text(vm.place?.isSaved ?? false ? "Saved" : "Want to go")
```

---

Maybe separating the code a bit helps it to be more clear:

```
let optionalIsSaved: Optional<Bool> = vm.place?.isSaved
let defaultedIsSaved: Bool = optionalIsSaved ?? false
Text(defaultedIsSaved ? "Saved" : "Want to go")
```

Comment: Hmm, how come this works? I thought simply checking `vm.place?.isSaved ? true : false` would suffice as a boolean check

Comment: More info added to the answer